# GlassFish Server update center installation times out

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I've installed a GlassFish Server instance into Netbeans, and I'm trying to install its update center. I have run Netbeans as an Administrator under Windows 7.

I'm on a fast internet connection, pkg.oracle.com seems to load rather fast from the browser. Still, I am keeping on getting this error:

```
C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.0>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java" -Dimage.path="C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.0\bin\\.." -jar "C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.0\bin\\..\pkg/lib/pkg-bootstrap.jar" "C:\Users\velosyp\AppData\Local\Temp\pkg-bootstrap1368.props" 
Proxy: Using system proxy settings.
Install image: C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.0
Installing pkg packages.
Downloading 2 packages.
Downloading pkg (514 files, 6 463 109 bytes).
Downloading python2.4-minimal (278 files, 3 828 949 bytes).
Executing 906 install actions.
Installing updatetool packages.
Downloading 2 packages.
Downloading updatetool (564 files, 4 632 599 bytes).
Input/output error: Read timed out

Could not download application packages. This could be because:
  - a proxy server is needed to access the internet. Please ensure that
    the system proxy server settings in your Internet Options control panel
    (under Connections:LAN Settings) are correct, or set the HTTP_PROXY
    environment variable to the full URL of the proxy server.
  - the package server or network connection is slow.
    If you are getting time out errors you can try setting the
    PKG_CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT and PKG_CLIENT_READ_TIMEOUT
    environment variables and try again. For example to increase
    the timeouts to 300 seconds set them to 300
  - the package server is down or otherwise inaccessible or it is
    generating invalid data. Please contact the provider of the package
    server.
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: P.s. I am  not behind a proxy server.

Comment: Please check the Network Connection settings in Netbeans for any unusual values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a problem with the slow GlassFish update server. Here are some steps you can try:

You should retry first to see if the error occurs again. You can start a cmd, navigate to the \glassfish\bin directory and run updatetool.bat so you can see the output which is printed after the one you posted.

If you are behind a proxy you should make sure it is setup correctly in the system settings.

You can also try to install the updates through the GlassFish admin console. Start your GlassFish instance and navigate to http:\localhost:4848. On the bottom of the left menu click on Updatetool. There you can choose and install the desired updates.

Another option is to change the timeouts of the pkg tool. To set the timeout to 300 seconds do the following in a cmd (on Windows):

```
set PKG_CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=300
set PKG_CLIENT_READ_TIMEOUT=300
```

You last (ok, there may be other ones) option is to just skip the update process and do the tutorial with the current version. It should work anyway and I can see in my GlassFish update center that there is only an update for the tutorial documentation at the moment.
 and

> [check this](https://blogs.oracle.com/dipol/entry/troubleshooting_glassfish_update_center)

Comment: Thank you, it worked! However, I find it more than strange that they do not prepare themselves for their average server load...

Answer (score 0):

Try `pkg` first, then `pkg install updatetool`.

Another option is to `bootstrap` the (smaller) `pkg` command first, and then use the `pkg` command to install `updatetool` (instead of bootstrapping updatetool). For example:

```
pkg list
```

Answer 'y' to bootstrap the `pkg` command. Then:

pkg install updatetool

to install `updatetool` using the `pkg` command.