# Cannot install Glassfish update tool

Tags: glassfish, java-ee-7, glassfish-4

Firstly, there are related posts:
[GlassFish Server update center installation times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628579/glassfish-server-update-center-installation-times-out)
[Java EE 7 updatetool installation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807055/java-ee-7-updatetool-installation-fails)

I got my Java EE 7 SDK (Update 3) from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html

I have tried each of the solutions in the above posts and here: https://blogs.oracle.com/dipol/troubleshooting-glassfish-update-center

Including:

- In the cmd prompt running `set PKG_CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=300` and `set PKG_CLIENT_READ_TIMEOUT=300` before updatetool in `C:\glassfish4\bin\updatetool.bat` (c:\glassfish4 in my install directory - all settings were default, including install update tool...).
- Set above mentioned timeout to much larger values - doesn't appear to make a difference at all, the process basically bombs immediately.
- Running `C:\glassfish4\bin\updatetool.bat` many times.
- Triple checking that I didn't somehow configure a proxy server in my sleep.
- Use the update tool via the Glassfish admin console at `http://localhost:4848` (seems to show no available update or add-ons, which seems odd..)

I get the following screenshot when I run `C:\glassfish4\bin\updatetool.bat`[image: cmd screenshot]

I have no idea why the error would be proxy related, unless it happened to be something on their end. Interestingly, If I go directly to the URL mentioned (via Chrome) I get the following page:
[image: proxy error page]

What could possibly be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updatetool was a commercial feature of Oracle GlassFish. Any update functionality relied on Oracle providing a site where updates could be hosted. Since Oracle GlassFish is no longer supported, this site no longer exists so the updatetool won't work any more.

Rather than downloading GlassFish from Oracle, you should download it from [the official open source site, hosted on GitHub](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/). Alternatively, if you really do need support, you could try Payara Server which is open source, and derived from GlassFish, but has support available (*disclaimer: I work for Payara*)

Comment: No problem. I wrote some instructions for upgrading Payara Server which will apply to GlassFish. They are focused on a Linux OS, but the point is that all your configuration is within either the domain directory or node directories and they can be copy/pasted safely from one GlassFish installation to another
https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/user-guides/upgrade-payara.html